# EF Does not execute delete command

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the entity framework as my data access layer.
But for some tasks (e.g. batch deleting), I want to use raw SQL commands.

But at this point EF surprises me, because it seems to execute the DML, but does not do anything.

If I run the sql directly, it executes and deletes the data as expected. So what do I do wrong?

```
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var sqlTime = string.Concat("DELETE FROM SYNCING_CONTENT WHERE ID in (SELECT SyncContent_Id FROM SYNCING WHERE EXPIRATION < GETDATE());");
        var deleted = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlTime);

        return deleted;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        const string SQL_TIME = "DELETE FROM SYNCING_CONTENT WHERE ID in (SELECT SyncContent_Id FROM SYNCING WHERE EXPIRATION < GETDATE())";
        var deleted = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL_TIME);

        return deleted;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use string.concact for a single string?

Comment: You are right. The string.Concat is not necessary. But that does not affect the executeSqlCommand

Comment: @BitKFu I never said that it was the problem. If that was the problem, I would have made it into an answer :)

Comment: Do I have to commit such changes? Or do I have to open a transaction for it? And if so, how can i achive that?

Comment: @BitKFu No you don't have to commit. Does your SQL work if you execute it directly to the db without .net?

Comment: yes it does. it deletes the expected rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the ; from your SQL string.

Also the issue may be due to the passing of GETDATE() in your sql string, I know this an issue if you pass it as a sql parameter.

Try

```
const string SQL_TIME = @"DELETE FROM SYNCING_CONTENT WHERE ID in (SELECT SyncContent_Id FROM SYNCING WHERE EXPIRATION < {0})";
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL_TIME, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: no. Even without the semicolon at the end it does not delete anything.

Comment: That does not work either, because it throws an exception because of incorrect sql syntax. And before you question: I tried it prior with CONVERT sql syntax. But that does not seem to be the problem. Do you know if I can log the SQLs send out to the SQL Server?

Comment: @BitKFu - you can use Tools/sql profiler to view the executed sql

Comment: @BitKFu - try using parameterised sql - also you are setting var deleted = to the result of the sql being run but your sql is not returning any value.